# jq: How to look up a JSON object by name read from another object?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "contexts": {
        "context1": {
            "mydata": "value1"
        },
        "context2": {
            "mydata": "value2"
        }
    },
    "current_context": "context2"
}
```

I'd like to use `jq` to output the value of `mydata` for the context indicated by `current_context`. The above would output `value2`. If I change the JSON to have `"current_context": "context1"`, I'd get `value1`.

Given two invocations of jq, and the above JSON content in a file called `jq.json`, this works:

```sh
jq -r --arg context "$(jq -r '.current_context' jq.json)" '.contexts | to_entries[] | select(.key == $context) | .value.mydata' jq.json
```

Is there a way to do this with a single invocation of jq?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
jq -r '.contexts[.current_context].mydata' file.json
```

You could also use a variable:

```
jq -r '.current_context as $cc|.contexts[$cc].mydata' file.json
```

Answer (score 2):

and here's an alternative to jq solution, based on a walk-path unix utility **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**:

```
bash $ jtc -w'[current_context]<cc>v[^0]<cc>t[mydata]' file.json
"value2"
bash $
```

walk path (`-w`) breakdown:

- `[current_context]<cc>v` - get to the `current_context` value and memorize it in the namespace `cc` (directive `<cc>v` does it)
- `[^0]<cc>t[mydata]` - reset walk path back to root (`[^0]`) and recursively search for the label (tag) stored in the namespace (`<cc>t`), then address found JSON object by label `mydata`.

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` - shell cli tool for JSON operations